# What was the difference between Hussars and Chasseurs à Cheval in the 19th Century French army?

Tags: france, cavalry, army, napoleonic

As far as I can discover, in 19th Century France, Chasseurs à Cheval and Hussars were both light cavalry with little or no armour, prioritizing speed over protection, armed with sabres and carbines, used especially for reconnaissance, raids and pursuit, although they could also take part in charges on the battlefield. They both had elaborately decorated uniforms.

'Chasseur' is the French for 'hunter', like the German Jäger, in a military context implying 'light' troops, who relied on speed to get themselves out of trouble rather than heavy armaments and armour.

Yet the two were considered to be different, and light cavalry regiments were designated either Hussars or Chasseurs à Cheval, not both. What was the difference and how important was it?

Comment: Documenting your preliminary research will improve the probability of getting an answer and the quality of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between Chasseurs à Cheval and Hussars is that, while both were light cavalry, Chasseurs were ALSO expected to act as dismounted infantry if the situation called for it and were trained accordingly.  This in turn effected the types of missions they were assigned to.  Hussars got a lot of what a wargamer/armchair historian would consider "traditional" light cavalry roles on the battlefield (scouting, harassment, etc) whereas the Chasseurs were often assigned to convoy protection, guarding lines of communication and so forth, though they could and did perform traditional battlefield light cavalry roles if required.

Generally speaking the Hussar regiments were considered more prestigious because they are "true" cavalry, whereas the Chasseurs à Cheval were supposed to fight dismounted, and indeed many were former dragoon regiments "converted" to Chasseurs à Cheval.  In the ranks of "prestige" pure cavalry tended to view dragoons as basically infantry and therefor inferior, but there were some famous Chasseurs à Cheval regiments that probably "outweighed" the less prestigious Hussar regiments, depending on who you asked at the time!

Most of this information can be found on the wikipedia pages for Hussars and Chasseurs, with any gaps filled by my own knowledge of Napoleonic cavalry formations.

Comment: Not a word of this is supported by [the alleged reference (auto-translated)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasseur_%C3%A0_cheval): "*The first French cavalry unit which received the name of chasseurs, is the chasseurs de Fischer (1743-1761). ... It then frequently happened that Austrian hussars seized French horses; to take them back, a body of partisans is created by Fischer, who will “hunt” the mounts. ... It then frequently happened that Austrian hussars seized French horses; to take them back, a body of partisans is created by Fischer, who will “hunt” the mounts.*"

Comment: Pieter you 100% missed the sections where it talks about French Dragoon regiments being re-designated as Chasseurs, and the general use of Hussars and Chasseurs in the relevant sections.  Also I'm not sure why you're on the french wiki for Chasseurs a Cheval instead of the english ones for Hussars and Chasseurs, which would be my source.

Comment: Fine: From [**Dragoon** in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragoon): "*By the Seven Years' War in 1756, their primary role in most European armies had progressed from that of mounted infantry to that of heavy cavalry. ... Their original responsibilities for scouting and picket duty had passed to hussars and similar light cavalry corps in the French, Austrian, Prussian, and other armies. ... *" 1/2

Comment: "*During the Napoleonic Wars, dragoons generally assumed a cavalry role, though remaining a lighter class of mounted troops than the armored cuirassiers. Dragoons rode larger horses than the light cavalry and wielded straight, rather than curved swords. ... while in 1811 six regiments were converted to Chevau-Legers Lanciers; they were often used in battle to break the enemy's main resistance.*" No mention of conversion to *Chasseurs au Cheval*; only of conversion to lance-equipped *Chevau-Legers*. 2/2

Comment: Dario, don't mind Geerkens too much. Try to ignore him. Being always right is one of his lovable characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So it sounds as though Chasseurs à Cheval overlapped in functions with both Hussars and dragoons, which seems complicated and confusing, but presumably it made sense to them.